# Deny access to all files in a directory unless a specific php page is referrer

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have files stored in a directory "uploads/downloads" which are accessed through a php file in the manner of https://www.example.com/request_file.php?file=123. That PHP file queries a database table and returns a file stored in the directory mentioned.

Using htaccess (I presume) how can I deny access to any files in the "uploads/downloads" directory unless the are being accessed through the request_file.php page?

Comment: You could just `Deny from all` / `Require all denied` (depending on Apache version) to block direct access to that directory completely - the PHP file will still be able to retrieve and serve it (permissions allowing).

Comment: Referer is easily spoofed, so blocking hits that have the wrong referer will just pose a minor inconvenience to anybody looking to get the files. If you want to do it more thoroughly, you'd put the files outside the web server's document root and then use PHP to `readfile()` them. (Or something to that effect...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !request_file.php
RewriteRule ^uploads/downloads/ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was needing. How would I go about redirecting them to a certain (single) page rather than just delivering a 404?

Comment: I changed the last line to RewriteRule ^uploads/downloads/ https://www.example.com/access-restricted [R,L] and this seems to work.