# How to reference the current directory in .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I have my files in the root directory on 000webhost. This is the public_html folder. In the example given in the link below, the files in a folder are prevented from direct access.

[Deny access to all files in a directory unless a specific php page is referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440484/deny-access-to-all-files-in-a-directory-unless-a-specific-php-page-is-referrer)

I would like to keep all my files in the root directory public_html rather than putting some in a separate folder. I also would like to prevent direct access to any file except for login.php, which I intend to login to my home page home.php. How would I go about changing the last line from the above link to refer to my root directory instead of a sub folder, and add exception to login.php?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !login.php
RewriteRule ^uploads/downloads/ - [L,R=404]
```

I would like to modify the third line `RewriteRule ^uploads/downloads/ - [L,R=404]` so that

1. Instead of referencing the folder `uploads/downloads/` I reference my root directly `public_html` in `000webhost`, because all my files are placed there for convenience.
2. I add exception to my login page `login.php`, so that my `login.php` can be directly access while no other file can be directly accessed.