# need explanation on .htaccess syntax

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in my folder that prevents direct access to all files in this folder. Basically, I used this link as reference. [Deny access to all files in a directory unless a specific php page is referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440484/deny-access-to-all-files-in-a-directory-unless-a-specific-php-page-is-referrer)

But I'm not sure what the syntax on the final line means, specifically what the ^ and the - do. I noticed it works if I delete the dash and keep the caret. Much appreciated if anyone can explain the syntax on the final line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !../login.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !home.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !table.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !1_3_5_7_8_10_12.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !4_6_9_11.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !2Leap.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !2NotLeap.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```